# Cannot set cookie on init hook

Tags: wordpress, cookies, hook

I have a weird problem when trying to set a cookie with the init hook (I must say I'm new on WP)

This is the code that's not working:

plugin.php file:

```
...
require_once( PLUGIN_DIR . 'class.plugin.php' );
add_action( 'init', array( 'Plugin', 'init_hooks' ) );
...
```

class.plugin.php file:

```
class Plugin {

    private static function init_hooks() {
        ...
        add_action('init',array('Plugin','setCookieAction'));
        ...
    }
    public static function setCookieAction(){
        setcookie('mycookie', $_GET['myCookie'], time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
```

However, if I modify the class to this:

class.plugin.php

```
class Plugin {

    private static function init_hooks() {
        ...
        setcookie('mycookie', $_GET['myCookie'], time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
        ...
    }
}
```

The cookie is being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an earlier hook to set up the actions that need to run on init:

`add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Plugin', 'init_hooks' ) );`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I'm curious why 'nesting' init hooks doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the priority parameters being identical, seems like this works too: `add_action( 'init', array( 'Plugin', 'init_hooks' ), 0 );`